# minha página html fica com ? (mas estou enviando coisas via post). http://localhost/SistemaAline/formulario.html?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Minha página carrega assim (abaixo)
http://localhost/SistemaAline/formulario.html

depois que envio dados para o php e retorno eles pra mesma página usando jquery, ela volta com ?
http://localhost/SistemaAline/formulario.html? e aí uns updates não funcionam direito, apenas quando recarrego a página sem o ?

Comment: Sem o código só podemos partir da especulação e isso não agregará em nada. Poderia [edit] e construir um [mcve] do problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece porque muito provavelmente o método de envio do seu `<form>` está como `GET`, ou nem foi configurado. sugiro que adicione a seguinte tag `method='POST'`, ao seu formulário.

Exemplo:

```
<form method="POST" action="página">
</form>
```